# java - printer window to select available client printer

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt

I have a web based application in java. I have a button on UI on click of that i want to show all the available printers on client computer, so that user can select a printer.

Following this link - `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html`

I have tried this :

```
   public static String printLabel( byte[] outputImage)
            throws LabelServiceException {
        try {           

              PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

                PrintService printService=null;
                if(printerJob.printDialog())
                {
                    printService = printerJob.getPrintService();
                }
                DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
                Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(outputImage, flavor, null);
                if(printService!=null) {
                    DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
                    printJob.print(doc, null);
                    return "success";
                }
                return "error";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LabelServiceException("Unable to print", e);
        }
    }
```

This opens a printer dialog :

[image]

I am not sure if its showing the client printer, because i am running from localhost i cant figure out.
When i deploy this code on server this printer window is not showing up.

Thanks

Comment: any log genrated?

Comment: no errors are coming in server logs.